# Matlab internal error Mex file

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I am trying to use the following package:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ssmodels/

It says in the readme that one should first run the 'mexall' file (from the csrc directory of the package) to generate all the mexes that are needed for the C files.

I can successfully run this file, but right after that, when I compile any of the demos I get an internal error and Matlab closes. I have tried rerunning the file multiple times but I keep getting the same.

Does anyone know what I could do to resolve this?

Comment: Any errors or stack traces from MATLAB?

Comment: @chappjc No errors are shown, how can I show stack traces?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. If you are using the 64-bit version of MATLAB then try to use the 32-bit version. Also make sure that you have a C compiler installed on your system and then run `mex -setup`.

Comment: Thanks. Installing a 32-bit version solely to get this to work doesn't seem like a great solution to me though. I have a C compiler, and the mexall program compiles without a problem. The issue occurs AFTER the compilation of this program, if I then run one of the demo's I get the internal Matlab errors.

Comment: yes i know, i had the same problem, but the 64-bt version of Matlab don't detect the C compiler. when executing mex- setup, 64-bit version don't display the C compiler among the compilers displayed